# Is there a way to count tags on a physical (PDF) page using XSL-FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Here is the scenario.  I have an XML document which contains  tags.  I want to create a transform that does this

```
<tag>content A</tag>           1. content A
<tag>content B</tag>  ---->    2. content B
<tag>content C</tag>           3. content C
```

but only if the tag contents appear on the same physical page.  The numbering should restart on each new page.  Is there any way to do this using XSL-FO?  I know with latex the only way to accomplish something like this is to run latex twice, with the interim document used to determine content page placement.

Comment: Some FO engines support an intermediate format which allows you to do additional processing based on how the page was actually generated.  This is not standardized, so the specifics will depend on the engine you are using.  I know RenderX's XEP engine has an XML-based format you can post-process before PDF is generated.

Comment: Do the tags correspond to lines as it does in your example? Or can they exist on the same line or carry over multiple lines?

Comment: There is not necessarily any correspondence between tags and lines.  There is variable amounts of content which can appear between the tags; I just left this out in order to clarify the example.

Comment: I have RenderX and Antenna House licenses available, but a 2-pass solution will probably be too much for the end-users to handle.  I have a support ticket in on this with Antenna House.  If I get an answer back, I'll post the solution back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell (and as confirmed by the Antenna House tech support team), **there is no way to do this using standard XSL-FO**.  Antenna House offers  <axf:footnote*/> extensions which include the ability to set an axf:footnote-number-reset="page" attribute, and as suggested in the comments, RenderX offers a generic mechanism which might be used for this purpose, but both of these involve vendor-specific extensions to the language.

This points to a number of shortcomings in XSL-FO that really should have been addressed a long time ago with a 2.0 version of the specification.  A w3c committee to develop an XSL-FO 2.0 spec was formed and then disbanded quite some time ago; I have no idea why, as I find the tool indispensable for a large class of document to PDF conversions.